# How to remove a record by id in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a function to remove a record in Codeigniter, but it is not working properly.

This is my buttons on `properties_list`

```
 <th>
  <div><a title="Delete" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right '.$disabled.'" data-href="'.base_url('admin/properties/del/'.$row['id']).'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div>
</th>
```

And my function DELETE on my controller `Properties_php`

```
  public function del($id = 0){
   $this->db->delete('ci_properties', array('propertie_id' => $id));
   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Imóvel removido!');
   redirect(base_url('admin/properties'));
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<th>
   <div>
      <a title="Delete" 
         class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right <?=$disabled?>" 
         data-href="<?=site_url('admin/properties/del/'.$row['id'])?>" 
         data-toggle="modal" 
         data-target="#confirm-delete">
         <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
      </a>
   </div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a title="Delete" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right '.$disabled.'" data-href="<?php echo base_url('admin/properties/del/'.$row['id']);?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php 
     echo base_url(); 
         ?>/admin/properties/del/<?php 
     echo $row['id']; 
         ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 5px;">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

define a var like $url
then place it in the href tag

```
 <th>
     <div>
     <?php $url = base_url('admin/properties/del/'.$row['id']);?>
      <a title="Delete" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right '.$disabled.'" 
       data-href="<?=$url?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i 
       class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
    </div>
  </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<th>
  <div><a title="Delete" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right '.$disabled.'" data-href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/properties/del/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div>
</th>
```

if this gives you an error, maybe your controller name doesn't match with link in data-href.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below code
      delete

```
function fnDelete(id)
{
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/properties/del'); ?>",  
method: 'POST',
data: { Autoid: id },    
success:function(result) {

   window.location.href= "<?php echo site_url('admin/properties'); ?>";
}
});
}

 public function del(){
$id=$this->input->post('Autoid');
    $this->db->delete('ci_properties', array('propertie_id' => $id));
         $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Imóvel removido!');
    redirect(base_url('admin/properties'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial request you are sending unprocessed PHP as the url.

use

```
<?= $variable;?>
<?= function();?>
```

to process the link contents in the php view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this

```
 <div><a title="Delete" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right '.$disabled.'" data-href="<?php echo base_url('admin/properties/del/'.$properties['propertie_id']);?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div>
```